# Modulo Arithmetic in mod 12

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently doing a math assignment and was wondering if I could get some clarification that I'm on the right track, I'm not looking for answers, because there are several of these questions so I need to understand what I'm doing.

for the question:

***Let f : Z12 → Z12 : x → 3x + 1 where arithmetic is done modulo 12***

For this, for example, if this question was done in mod 3 my answer would be:

3*0 + 1 = 1

3*1 + 1 = 4 which = 1

3*2 + 1 = 7 which = 1 ?

Am I way off here, there isn't much information on this kind of question

I added a picture to help clarify my question encase there is confusion

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h3Ld.png

Comment: You're not off at all. Note, however, that the question never asks you to calculate all values of $f$. It can be solved without resorting to brute force.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Arthur, can you please elaborate?

Comment: 1) Why did you do mod 3 when the question was mod 12, and 2) What exactly is the question?  Yes, the function is you take x, multiply it by 3 and adding one as expressed mod 3, but what are you supposed to do with it?  3) You have weird results because your choice of mod three just happened to be the number you are multiplying by so as 3 is 0 mod 3 you are simply multiplying be zero.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what question they are asking in a).  They say let f be a function.  Okay, it's a function.  If you are supposed to list all it's values (which isn't an unreasonable request) they should have said so.  Anyway, note question b) says to show it's not surjective nor injective.  That means  you aren't going to get 12 results nor will all the twelve results be unique, so don't be surprised when you don't.  You are definitely on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three results are $1, 4, 7$ as you've found. The next result is $f(3) = 3\cdot 3 +1 = 10$. Then we get to $f(4) = 3\cdot 4 + 1 = 13 \equiv 1$ again, and it loops around.

To solve (b), you first have to note that $f(0)\equiv f(4)$, so the function is not injective. Then, since $\Bbb Z_{12}$ is finite, a function that is not injective also cannot be surjective (so technically, you get away with calculating the function value only twice). If you want a more direct proof that the function is non-surjective, then first see that $3x \equiv 0, 3, 6$ or $9$. By adding $1$ to any of these, we get that no $x$ makes $f(x) = 0$, for instance.

For (c), there is a hint: "Find $x$ so that $5x \equiv 1$". That takes some trial and error (not much, remember that multiplying by an even number or a number divisible by $3$ is out of the question, so there is really only $4$ numbers to test). Let's say you've found such a number. We'll call it $a$. Then by taking some $x$, applying $g$ and then multiply by $a$ we get
$$
x \overset{g}\mapsto 5x + 1 \overset{\cdot a}\mapsto a\cdot 5x + a \equiv x + a
$$
Remember that what we really want is some way to get from $g(x) = 5x + 1$ back to $x$. Multiplying by $a$ gave us $x + a$, which means that multiplying by $a$ and *then subtracting* $a$ gives us $x$. We write this as $g^{-1}(x) = ax - a$.

Once you have the formula, the rest of (c) is easy. "Show that it's invertible" is solved by saying "I have found the inverse". Calculating $g^{-1}(0)$ and $g^{-1}(11)$ is also straight-forward; do it like you did (a). It might be a bit of a cheat to do the problem in reverse order, but I think that's the easiest way.

Comment: Wow thanks! I had the same answers (although yours worded about 50x better) for a) and b) so that makes me feel a bit more confident but i was WAAYY off on c) thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

a) Let's seek for two different numbers modulo $12$ such that their image by $f(x)=3x+1$ is the same. We have $f(0)=f(4)=f(8)=1$ so $f$ is not injective.

If we know try to solve $3x+1\equiv 2 \pmod{12}$ this is equivalent to find $x$ such that $3x\equiv 1$. But modulo $12$ we have

$$\begin{align}
3&\times 0\equiv 0\\
3&\times 1\equiv 3\\
3&\times 2\equiv 6\\
3&\times 3\equiv 9\\
3&\times 4\equiv 0\\
3&\times 5\equiv 3\\
3&\times 6\equiv 6\\
3&\times 7\equiv 9\\
3&\times 8\equiv 0\\
3&\times 9\equiv 3\\
3&\times 10\equiv 6\\
3&\times 11\equiv 9
\end{align}$$

And so $f$ is not surjective because we cannot find $x$ such that $f(x)=2$

b) consider now $g(x)=5x+1$. We have $5\times 5\equiv 1\pmod{12}$ so we have

$$g^{-1}(x)=5(x-1)$$

And $g$ is invertible.